# How to prepend the data size to a file

Tags: qt, serialization, qt5

I am saving the QAbstract tree model to a dat file

```
void saveTreeStructureToFile(const QModelIndexList &indexes , const std::string stdstrFilePath)
{
    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
    QByteArray data; //a kind of RAW format for datas
    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QList<TreeItem *> nodes;
    foreach(const QModelIndex &index, indexes) {
        TreeItem *node = getItem(index);
        if (!nodes.contains(node))
            nodes << node;
    }
    stream << nodes.count();
    foreach(TreeItem *node, nodes) {
        buildTree(node, stream);
    }
    mimeData->setData(s_treeNodeMimeType, data);
    std::string st = stdstrFilePath.substr(0, stdstrFilePath.size() - 3);
    st.append("dat");
    const QString path = st.c_str();
    QFile file(path);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QDataStream out(&file);
    out << *mimeData;
}
```

How can i prepend the size of total bytes to be written to the start of dat file.

Comment: Maybe so: `out << data.size() << *mimeData;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the size of the data and append it to your data stream at the beginning, like:

```
out << data.size() << *mimeData;
```